# MergeSorting C++, missing an element after running sort

Tags: c++, mergesort

I am trying to implement a merge sort algorithm, I have included my code and the output that shows me the problem. The array has 10 integers in it and when it sorts I lose the highest integer. I am unable to figure out why and I am sure it is right in front of my face. You can see after the 4th call to merging, an element is replaced with an element already in the array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sys/time.h>

using namespace std;

int mergeop = 0;
int mergeassign = 0;

//Merge
void merge(int h, int m, int uArray[], int vArray[], int mergeArray[]){
  int i = 1;
  int j = 1;
  int k = 1;
  while(i <= h && j <= m){
    if(uArray[i - 1] < vArray[j - 1]){
      mergeArray[k - 1] = uArray[i - 1];
      i++;
      mergeassign++;
    }
    else{
      mergeArray[k - 1] = vArray[j - 1];
      j++;
      mergeassign++;
    }
    k++;
    mergeop++;
  }
  if(i > h){
    for(int x = j; x <= m; x++){
      mergeArray[k - 1] = vArray[x - 1];
    }
  }
  else{
    for(int y = i; y <= h; y++){
      mergeArray[k - 1] = uArray[y - 1];
    }
  }
}
//Mergesort
void mergeSort(int n, int mergeArray[]){
  if(n>1){
    int h = (n / 2);
    int m = n - h;
    int uArray[h];
    int vArray[m];
    for(int i = 0; i < h; i++){
      uArray[i] = mergeArray[i];
    }

    cout << "\n";
    for(int j = m; j <= n; j++){
      vArray[j - (h + 1)] = mergeArray[j - 1];
    }
    cout << "\n";
    mergeSort(h, uArray);
    mergeSort(m, vArray);
    merge(h, m, uArray, vArray, mergeArray);
    cout << "\n Merging\n";
    for(int l = 0; l < n; l++){
        cout << mergeArray[l] << "|";
    }
    cout << "\nU\n";
    for(int l = 0; l < h; l++){
      cout << uArray[l] << "|";
    }
    cout << "\nV\n";
    for(int l = 0; l < m; l++){
      cout << vArray[l] << "|";
    }
    cout << "\n";
  }
}
int main(){
  cout << "Sorting Comparisons\n\n";
  string infile;
  int *exchangeArray;
  int *insertionArray;
  int *mergeArray;
  int *heapArray;
  int *selectionArray;
  int count = 0;
  struct timespec start, end;
  // Get file name
  cout << "\nIan Kelly\nSorting\n";
  cout << "\n";
  cout << "Enter filename: \n";
  cin >> infile;
  ifstream file;
  // Open file
  cout << "Filename entered: " << infile << "\n\n";
  file.open(infile);
  assert(file.is_open());
  //Check if file is empty
  if(file.peek() == '\0'){
    cout << "\nFile Empty.\n";
  }
  //Read Data
  else{
    //Declare and create Arrays
    exchangeArray = new int[500];
    mergeArray = new int[500];
    string inLine;
    while(getline(file, inLine)){
      exchangeArray[count] = stoi(inLine);
      mergeArray[count] = stoi(inLine);
      count++;
    }
    cout << "\n|";
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
      cout << exchangeArray[i] << "|";
    }

    //
    // Run Merge Sort
    //
    cout << "\n\n Merge Sort Out:\n\n";
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start);
    mergeSort(count, mergeArray);
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &end);
    cout << "Start time: " << start.tv_sec << "s";
    cout << " " << start.tv_nsec << "ns\n";
    cout << "End time: " << end.tv_sec << "s";
    cout << " " << end.tv_nsec << "ns\n";
    cout << "Elapsed time: " << (start.tv_sec - end.tv_sec);
    cout << "s " << (end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec);
    cout << "ns\n|";
    for(int k = count - 1; k >= 0; k--){
      cout << mergeArray[k] << "|";
    }
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "\nRecords: " << count << "\n";
    cout << "Assignments: " << mergeassign;
    cout << "\nOperations: " << mergeop << "\n\n\n";

  }
}
```

OUTPUT 
'''

```
 Merge Sort Out:
Merging
467|1417|
U
1417|
V
467|
Merging
3240|3339|
U
3339|
V
3240|
Merging
418|3339|3240|
U
418|
V
3240|3339|
**Merging
418|467|1417|3240|3240|
U
467|1417|
V
418|3339|3240|
Merging
97|3235|
U
3235|
V
97|

Merging
795|2435|
U
2435|
V
795|**
Merging
795|2435|2521|
U
2521|
V
795|2435|
Merging
97|795|2435|2521|3235|
U
97|3235|
V
795|2435|2521|
Merging
97|418|467|795|1417|2435|2521|3235|3240|795|
U
418|467|1417|3240|3240|
V
97|795|2435|2521|3235|
Start time: 1573865718s 996192676ns
End time: 1573865719s 4844192ns
Elapsed time: -1s -991348484ns
|795|3240|3235|2521|2435|1417|795|467|418|97|
```

Original array

```
1417
467
418
3339
3240
3235
97
2521
2435
795
```

Comment: You don't increase `k` when you merge the left-over elements in. You actually have this problem even earlier, `418|3339|3240|` is merged wrongly.

Comment: Thank you so much, I knew I was missing something simple.